# How can I arrange items in a table - MVC3 view (Index.cshtml)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to show the amount of different types of vitamins present in specific types of food samples, using ASP.NET MVC3. How can I display this in my View (Index.cshtml) ?

an example:
[image]

And these are my codes:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    @foreach (var m in Model)
    {
         foreach (var v in m.Vitamins)
         {
              <th>@v.Name</th> 
         }           
    }
</tr>

   @foreach (var m in Model)
   {
         foreach (var f in m.Foods)
        {
             <tr>
                  <td>@f.Type</td>
             </tr> 
        }          
   }
</table>

@*The amount of Vitamins in each food:

       var a in m.AmountOfVitamins
       @a.Amount

*@
```

Comment: I dont know how to place the `@a.Amount´ in the right cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the **Amount** collection is ordered correctly (I'm guessing yes), then you could use simply:

```
foreach (var f in m.Foods)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@f.Type</td>
        foreach (var a in m.AmountOfVitamins)
        {
            <td>a.Amount</td>
        }
    </tr> 
}
```

If they're in some other random order, then you'd need a way to sort them according to the header columns A, B, C, D ...

Comment: Thanks, do you know where I can find any good tutorial about sorting according to header columns?