# How can I model this relational database, and have all the data in collection classes

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

How can I model this relational database in EF in such a way that I can have List collection classes for the Food types, Vitamins and the amounts of vitamins in each food type?

[image]

Comment: Using Entity framework to model this?

Comment: my thoughts went instantly to List<List<>> ... :D but im mentally twisted like that

Comment: Because what I see is you have 5 fields for this table. The food type, then vitamin A,b,c,d . Question is , why are you displaying this as a matrix? is this layout constant or subject to change?

Comment: yes, its a matrix and the layout is constant.

Comment: Are you asking how to model your 2NF table in a relational way? Or did you want somthing else/more?

Comment: @Jodrell, I need to model it and show it in the layout of ASP.NET (MVC3): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613716/how-can-i-arrange-items-in-a-table-mvc3-view-index-cshtml#comment13752972_10613716

Answer (score 2):

To model your table in a realtional database, which I think must be the question, you would have 3 entities. `FoodType`, `Vitamin` and the `FoodTypeVitamin` relationship.

`FoodType` would have one attribute called `Id`, values being 1,2,3,4 etc.

`Vitamin` would have an `Id` and a `Name` attribute, values being

```
Id    Name
1     'A'
2     'B'
3     'C'
4     'D'
```

`FoodTypeVitamin` would have a foreign key to both `FoodType` and `Vitamin` and a `Mg` attribute to hold the number of milligrams for each relationship. So the data may start like this

```
VitmainId  FoodTypeId  Mg
1          1           200
3          1           100
2          2           50
3          2           11
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use EF Code First you might do something like this:

```
public class Vitamin 
{
    [Key]
    public String Name {get; set;}
    public double Amount {get; set;}
    public virtual Food Food {get; set;}
}

public class Food
{
    [Key]
    public int FoodID {get; set;}
    public String FoodName {get; set;}
    public virtual List<Vitamin> Vitamins {get; set;}
}

public DataContext: DbContext 
{
     public DbSet<Vitamin> Vitamin {get; set;}
     public DbSet<Food> Foods {get; set;}
}
```